# Windows 10 Universal app screen size on launch not working

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I had read a ton about setting the app window size on launch. Basically, my app is launching full screen everytime. I want to restrict it to a pre-defined size when it launches. However, nothing seems to be working. Here is what I have done so far:

1. I have put the following:

   ```
   var desiredSize = new Size(400, 600);
   ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().ExitFullScreenMode();
   ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(desiredSize);
   ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = desiredSize;
   ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
   ```

And have tried that snippet in first the constructor for MainPage.xaml.cs (which didn't work), then just above

```
Window.Current.Activate();
```

In App.xaml.cs which also didn't work. Based on some reading, I also tried adding:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(desiredSize);
```

Both after Window.Current.Activate in App.xaml.cs and at the end of the constructor in MainPage.xaml.cs.

I did notice that in MainPage.xaml.cs, I could do:

```
 this.Width = 400;
 this.Height = 600;
```

And that does work to size the MainPage frame within the window properly but the overall Window stays the same size.

I can manually drag the window to the size I want after it launches but I want it so simply just launch this size everytime. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Just using `ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size { Height = 550, Width = 360 };` and
            `ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;` in the MainPage Constructor works fine for me.

Comment: There must be something else that is blocking or preventing this. I am not sure what it could be. It does not work in my project but i can confirm your findings, if i create a new project it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set minimum window size if it's less than default

```
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size { Width = 400, Height = 600});
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(400, 600);
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
```

Call this in **App.xaml.cs** before **Window.Current.Activate();**

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is one of the things listed in my post that i tried. it does not work. there must be something else in my app that is conflicting.

Comment: Marking this answer as correct because it is the correct way to do what I needed to do. However, in my case, it was not working when I would debug. I did a full clean and rebuild and now it works. That said, I also noticed that it may not work on the first launch but on all subsequent launches, it will respect your screen size request.

Comment: Yes, it did not work the first time you debug after making the change!

Comment: Guys, that would never work the first time. Reason is simple - In order to correctly set the ViewSize, you need to have PreferredLaunchWindowingMode  as PreferredLaunchViewSize. The problem is, that is Auto by default. Setting it to a different value works ONLY for the next launches. That means for the current launch you're stuck with Auto and can't resize.