# ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView() is unpredictable. Doesn't always work in my UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

When I call `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView()` when launching my app UWP desktop app, it works most of the time, but more often than it should, it simply fails to resize the window. If the conditions are always the same, why is it that I get a different result sometimes? Is there a fix for this behavior?

Comment: I think it is not random. Every time the App starts in PreferredLaunchWindowingMode set to Auto, the method does nothing. When set to PreferredLaunchViewSize, it always works (for me at least).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898930/windows-10-universal-app-screen-size-on-launch-not-working). `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView()` method is not so good for launch, it is for in-app actions. Different results may come from anything, when you close the app, it saves position from last session, it may come from that, in other cases, even async operations can lead to different results. In UWP that is not rare case.